Search a dataframe of paragraphs against a dataframe of substrings and return the substrings and the paragraph they matched against
I am searching through a web page against a list of names in a data frame. If a name appears in a paragraph I want to know which paragraph so I can parse certain parts of that paragraph and then associate it with the name.
I have two data frames:
dfrule which is made up of 'Paragraphs' and 'Ids' and eldf which is made up of 'Names' and 'Ids'
eldf:
{'Name':{...,
         1704: 'Satco',...}}

dfrule:
{'Paragraphs: {0:" Words words words Satco", ...}, 'id': {0: 0,1: 1,...}}

My desired output would be the entry 'Satco' with the Id of the paragraph it appears in.
So far I have:
substring_matches = eldf['name'].apply(lambda s1: dfrule['Paragraphs'].apply(lambda s2: s1 in s2).any()
matchdf = eldf[substring_matches]

This gives me every name on the list that matched against any paragraph but not the Id of which paragraph it matched against. How would I be able to associate it with the paragraph id?
So I get {'Name":{1704:'Satco'}, 'Paragraph id':{0:0}}

Please provide a sample of data, preferably in df.to_dict() constructor form, so that we can see what is going on

Since there is no provided data, I had to speculate as to what it could look like. I'm not fully clear on the exact parameters of the dataframes, nor the desired output format, but below is an example where you can find all of the paragraph IDs if they contain the value under the 'Names' column, ignoring case.
If you want the function to be more strict about case, then delete the 'case=False' argument from the str.contains call.
import pandas as pd

dfrule_dict = {'Paragraphs': ['Example paragraph one.', 'Example two.',
                              'Third example.', 'This is the fourth.'],
               'Ids': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
dfrule = pd.DataFrame(dfrule_dict)

eldf_dict = {'Names': ['Example', 'two', 'paragraph', 'Foo', 'Bar', '.', 'Master Chief'],
             'Ids': [111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117]}
eldf = pd.DataFrame(eldf_dict)

def find_paragraphs(name):
    ids = dfrule[dfrule['Paragraphs'].str.contains(name, case=False)]['Ids'].tolist()
    return ids

eldf['paragraph_ids'] = eldf['Names'].apply(find_paragraphs)

print(eldf)

Below is the output produced in this example.


Did you try my answer and if so did it solve your question?
